# Calulating the compression deformation using strain data measured by strain gauge _ material engineering

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, experimental-physics, deformation

I'm studying material engineering and conducting some experiment.

The experiment was measuring the strain of long steel bar.
The bar is compressed from left side and deformed shortened.
Using strain gauge along the steel bar, strain of each position is measured.

How can i calculate the total deformation using measured data?

Answer (score 0):

First a disclaimer: that you can't really precisely obtain the actual deformation of the specimen, you can only get an estimate. The result will be dependent on the geometry of the specimen (if its strain, or a dogbone, what type of dogbone etc), and the grip distance.

However, an educated guess would do the following:

assuming:

- the average strain is $\epsilon$ just before structure.
- the grip distance is L

the total deformation $\Delta L $ should be in the order of
$$\Delta L = \epsilon \cdot L$$